# How to add and use plugins to an application created with phonegap?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to add plugins and use them in my android application created with phonegap. To create the application I follow the simple tutorial phonegap web:

```
$ phonegap create my-app
$ cd my-app
$ phonegap run android
```

Then I want to add the plugin to delete cache and add in the config.xml
https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/876

```
<gap:plugin name="com.sharinglabs.cordova.plugin.cache" version="1.0.0" />
```

and then in my controller I added javascript code to clear the cache:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', onDeviceReady);
function onDeviceReady()
{
        var success = function(status) {
            alert('Message: ' + status);
        }

        var error = function(status) {
            alert('Error: ' + status);
        }

        window.cache.clear( success, error );
}
```

I made some changes to fit my code, although I guess it will not be the problem:

```
var ViewController = function(){
    //Clean cache
    window.cache.clear(cacheSuccess, cacheError);
}

ViewController.prototype = {
    cacheSuccess: function(status) {
        alert('Message: ' + status);
    },

    cacheError: function(status) {
        alert('Error: ' + status);
    }
}
new ViewController();
```

The application does not load properly, I need to add some more js file? what could be the error?

Comment: what version of phonegap are you working with? To add a plugin in phonegap 3.0.0 you need to  use the following command from your local computer prompt `phonegap local plugin add https://github.com/moderna/cordova-plugin-cache.git`. see [here](https://github.com/Sharinglabs/cordova-plugin-cache/blob/42f70be/README.md) for details. The method of adding the plugin by editing the config.xml `<gap:plugin name="com.sharinglabs.cordova.plugin.cache" version="1.0.0" /> `is for building the phonegap app thru their build service. i.e `build.phonegap.com`

Comment: He had already tried to install it using this command in the directory of my application, folder, create the following at.modalog.cordova.plugin.cache plugins directory. My application does not work, I need something else?

Comment: My phonegap version 3.5.0-0.21.18